# C++ Создание экземпляров структуры сразу же после объявления самой структуры. Надо ли?

Tags: c++, ооп

друзья! Изучаю С++ и недавно наткнулся на такую вещь:

Есть сей код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    Point(int xin, int yin) { x = xin; y = yin; }
    int x;
    int y;
} s(3, 4);

int main() {
    std::cout << s.x << std::endl;
}
```

Итак, как мы видим, тут объявление экземпляра структуры сразу же после объявления самой структуры. И вопрос таков: зачем так делать? Стоит ли такое использовать или лучше отдельно писать

```
Point s(3, 4);
```

В той же глобальной области видимости?

Красиво ли так делать с точки зрения читаемого программирования?

---

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Глобальные переменные лучше просто так не делать. Объявите в main переменную нужного типа и все будет нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ: нет, ни в коем случае не стоит так делать! Общепринятая практика состоит в том, чтобы разделять объявления и реализацию. Объявления существуют только на стадии компиляции и размещаются, как правило, в h-файлах. Реализация же - это грубо говоря то, что после компиляции реально занимает место в исполняемом файле, как то код или данные программы. Соответственно, объявление структуры `Point` в данном примере - это, извиняюсь за тавтологию, объявление)) А объявление переменной типа `Point` - уже относится к реализации. А значит, их следует разделить. Например так:

```
//файл point.h
#ifndef __point_h__
#define __point_h__

struct Point {
    Point(int xin, int yin) { x = xin; y = yin; }
    int x;
    int y;
};

#endif //__point_h__
```

...

```
//Файл main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

Point s(3, 4);

int main() {
    std::cout << s.x << std::endl;
    return 0; //всё же корректнее возвращать значение из main()
}
```

Если программа небольшая, то разбивать на два файла, конечно, не обязательно, но всё равно объявления и реализация должны быть отделены друг от друга. Исходный текст следует подразделить на области. Обычно в начале идут include'ы, затем - область макроопределений (#define'ы), потом - объявления структур, классов, и прочих типов данных. И далее идут объявления глобальных переменных (если они есть), после них - функции (собственно код).

Comment: я бы не был бы столь категоричен, при этом оставив глобальную переменную:)

Comment: @KoVadim Глобальная переменная - это для примера (ведь и так тоже можно). А насчёт категоричности... Конечно, никто не может заставить структурировать код именно таким образом. Кроме последующего собственного опыта и товарищей по цеху, которым вероятно придётся в твоём коде разбираться)) С++ - не Python, в нём как угодно можно, вплоть до анархии самовыражения)) Вопрос состоял именно в том, стоит ли так делать. Мой ответ выше. С уважением.

Comment: **Есть такое правило: нет правил без исключений**. Я таким способом пользуюсь, если, например, мне нужна какая-то простенькая структура внутри функции, и более нигде она светиться не будет. Например, какая-то реализация RAII или что-то еще. Тогда я ничтоже сумняшеся объявляю ее и тут же создаю экземпляры. Считаю это вполне нормальным, удобным, приемлемым и так далее...

Comment: @Harry, ну так то да, только главное - не перегибать палку с такими исключениями. Я, например, всё же стараюсь строго придерживаться единого стиля своих исходников. Исключения могу делать в процессе написания и отладки того или иного модуля, но потом всё равно привожу весь код в стандартный вид. И практика показала, что это очень оправдано. Особенно, когда возвращаешься к своему коду спустя большой промежуток времени...

Comment: @Harry

Просто суть в том, что в С++ много всяких штук, тех же goto, но их настоятельно рекомендуют не использовать, от этого я и задаю такого рода вопросы. 
И вот не пойми, как делать правильнее, чтоб все (или почти) были довольны.
Вот я тоже, как и товарищ LShadow77 вне зависимости от величины структур стараюсь их разбить на файлы, однако вот вопрос тот же, оправдано ли

Comment: @DiHASTRO Понимаете... Освобождая всех от ответственности за мое мнение: если бы что-то было *категорически неприемлемо*, то оно бы в стандарт не вошло :) Поэтому относитесь к стандарту как к ПДД: нарушать не надо, но как именно и куда именно идти/ехать — это ваше дело. Конечно, если вы идете колонной, то идти надо в ногу, всем вместе (читай — использовать тот стиль кодирования, который принят в команде). Если движетесь самостоятельно — это ваше дело, главное — позаботьтесь о том, чтобы не заблудиться :)

Comment: `__point_h__` = зарезервированное имя (из-за `__`). </занудство>

Comment: @Harry согласен с вами :D

Comment: @HolyBlackCat надо же, всегда так делал - никаких проблем не было))

Comment: @DiHASTRO практически любые возможности C++ оправданы, если они повышают качество кода, делают его более понятным и структурированным. Взять, например, тот же `goto` - бывают ситуации, когда этот оператор оказывается очень полезным, т.к. без него код становится значительно сложнее. Но такие ситуации весьма редки и в подавляющем большинстве случаев использование `goto` совершенно неоправдано. Обобщая, можно сформулировать правило: никогда не следует отклоняться от стандартов, если на то нет весомых причин.

Comment: @LShadow77 *"всегда так делал - никаких проблем не было"* Если бы "запретная" фишка языка давала большое преимущество, я бы понял. А тут нелегальность исправляется легко, и такое исправление ничему особо не мешает.

Comment: @LShadow77 я понимаю, вот поэтому и хотел спросить насчёт стандарта. Просто, если я правильно понял, в нём ничего не прописано насчёт создания экземпляров таким образом. Посему решил спросить совета у более опытных дядек :D